# What groups have the property: All nontrivial isomorphic subgroups have a nontrivial intersection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is a generalization of my previous question: [What are all finite groups such that all isomorphic subgroups are identical?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689631/what-are-all-finite-groups-such-that-all-isomorphic-subgroups-are-identical)

Specifically, what finite groups $G$ have the following property: For any two subgroups $1 < H, H' < G$ that are isomorphic, then $H \cap H'$ is non-trivial.

Some quick results: This property is equivalent to all prime order cyclic subgroups being unique. Also, each of these subgroups are normal.

If $G$ is an abelian group, it turns out $G$ is cyclic. (Proof: $G=G_1 \times \cdots \times G_n$, each cyclic, with $|G_i|$ dividing $|G_{i+1}|$. Two factors share a common prime $p$, hence two disjoint copies of $C_p$, so no two factors exist.)

However, there are non-abelian groups that satisfies this condition (if I've thought through it right). Take the [Quaternion group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Quaternion_group), which from the subgroup lattice is easily seen to have the desired property.

Can the (non-abelian) groups with this property be easily characterized?

Answer (score 6):

The question has an answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250548/finite-groups-with-unique-subgroup-of-order-p-for-all-prime-divisors-of-g).

> [In such a group] every Sylow $p$-subgroup is either cyclic or generalized quaternion (because these are the only $p$-groups that have a unique subgroup of
>   order $p$). Apparently, Zassenhaus (in the 1930s) classified all
>   solvable groups where all the Sylow $p$-subgroups for odd primes are
>   cyclic, and where the Sylow 2-subgroup contains an index $2$ cyclic
>   subgroup (and Michio Suzuki, in the paper ''On finite groups with
>   cyclic Sylow subgroups for all odd primes'' from Amer. J. of Math in
>   1955 classified the non-solvable groups with the same properties).
>
> This gives a complete classification of the groups that meet your
>   condition.